# API Platform with Symfony won't show my resource entity

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am currently coding along the SymfonyCasts tutorial for API Platform. https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform
Right after creating my first entity in the tutorial's second chapter, the API browser application won't list my entity. So when calling the /api route in my browser, instead of the desired endpoints, I just get the "No operations defined in spec!" message.

I do not have access to the code included in the course, so I created a Symfony application from scratch. Please see the code on https://github.com/danschdev/shouts/tree/api-platform

No matter if I mark the entity as an API Platform resource directly in the entity creation dialog, or manually as described in the tutorial, the result stays the same. What might be missing?
I also took a look at the api_platform.yaml file, which looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the configuration you have maybe you should try to add line in api_platform.yaml config file :

```
api_platform:
    metadata_backward_compatibility_layer: false
```

In version 2.7 the default value is true, and if you want to use the new metadata system, it's necessary to set the `metadata_backward_compatibility_layer` to false

See more details here : [Upgrade guide](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/upgrade-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is due to caching. Try to clear/remove your cache and try again.

```
./bin/console clear:cache
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid neither `./bin/console cache:clear` nor `php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer` changed anything about the missing endpoint display.

Comment: @danschdev Check your `composer.json`. You have added `"api-platform/core": "^2.7",`, while your code is confirm version `^3.0`.